# getting string only in overloading >> operator istream:

Tags: c++, input, operators

i have Polynomial class. i also have a method that take string and convert it to polynomial.
now i try to implement this method for input operator:

```
istream& operator>> (istream &is, Poly& pol)
{
    //the string that we use:
    string str;

    //the new input override the old:
    pol.emptyPoly();


    //getting a string from user and put it into str:
   //????????????????????? 

   // convert the string to polynomial
   pol.sToPol(str);

   return is;
}
```

what am i need to put in //???????? to get the string from user and put it into str?

then when i will do:

```
Poly p1;
cin>>p1;
```

user will input string and it will be converted into polynomial in my method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
is >> str;
```

if string is without spaces

```
std::getline(is, str);
```

if there are spaces in string.

Comment: thanks but it is not working .
first souloution give me error:
error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

2nd dont find getline in std

Comment: @AviadChmelnik how about #include <string>?

Comment: i tried to edit the comment to :" my mistake!!, forgot to write include string" but the 5 minutes of editing was over.
thanks a lot man! you save my grade in "Introduction to OOP" :)